# How to generate formula from an cell like AutoFill

Tags: excel, vba

I have a cell (A3) has formula "=A1+A2". I want to calculate formula for B3 from formula A3 and result is "=B1+B2" like AutoFill function.
Something like that

```
Function GetNextFormula(fromCell as Range, toCell as Range)
     bla bla bla 
     GetNextFormula = "=B1+B2"
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you really need a function for this? I realize that the example has been simplified but it seems like a lot of work for what is essentially `Range("A3:B3").FillRight`

Comment: My customer want to compare 2 cell (A and B) and detect formula from cell B is autofill from cell A. My solution is: Get formula from A, generate formula for cell B and compare result to exist formula in cell B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The xlR1C1 formula will be the exact same in both cases. Taking the xlR1C1 formula from A3 and converting it to an xlA1 style formula relative to B3 with the [Application.ConvertFormula method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-convertformula-method-excel) will deliver the correct formula.

```
Function GetNextFormula(fromCell As Range, toCell As Range)

     GetNextFormula = Application.ConvertFormula(Formula:=fromCell.FormulaR1C1, _
                                                 FromReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1, _
                                                 ToReferenceStyle:=xlA1, _
                                                 ToAbsolute:=xlRelative, _
                                                 RelativeTo:=toCell)

End Function
```

Given your recent comment, you could just perform a StrCmp on the xlR1C1 formulas from A3 and B3. If B3's was generated with AutoFill or FillRight, they will be identical.

```
if range("A3").formular1c1 = range("B3").formular1c1 then
    debug.print "autofill match"
end if
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you save my weekend